# How can I embed two navbars with boostrap dinamically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need 2 Bootstrap navbars. Tha main one has some elements. When i click on one of the element, the second navbar should begin to show further clickable options.
Any idea how can I solve it? The picture represents what i mean it.[image]

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/11CTcdvzl8

Comment: Wondeful! Thank you :)